# Hide div with class name having space in it using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth rcbNoWrap" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; overflow: auto"> </div>
```

This is my div. I want to hide the div using the class name. I am not able to do as class name 
as space in it. It is only one class.

Comment: Class names cannot have spaces in them. Spaces denote separate classes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Class names can not have spaces in them. So you have to think of it as 2 class names.

Eg: `class="word1 word2"`

Can be selected with the following:

```
var myVar = $('.word1.word2');
```

In your specific case, it becomes:

```
$('.rcbScroll.rcbWidth.rcbNoWrap').hide();
```

Answer (score 4):

The spaces means multiple class names, you can use any of these classes to hide the `div`.

Example:

```
$(".rcbScroll").hide()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dot to join multiple `classes` in selector being separated by `space` character.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TtWZn/1/)**

```
$(".rcbScroll.rcbWidth.rcbNoWrap").hide();
```